# Linq Join Select to return a flatten List

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following Linq statement:

```
var permissions = (from ru in RoleUserStore
                  join role in RoleStore on ru.RoleId equals role.Id
                  where ru.UserId == user.Id
                  select role.Permissions).ToList();
```

My result is a `List<ICollection<Permission>>`. How do I do this correctly to have a flat List across all the Roles? I could not figure out how to do this.

Comment: I think SelectMany is what you need.

Comment: And you may want to add `.Distinct()` to it to cut all duplicates out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `ToList()` with `SelectMany(x => x).ToList()`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `SelectMany` which is in query syntax:

```
var permissions = from ru in RoleUserStore
                  join role in RoleStore on ru.RoleId equals role.Id
                  where ru.UserId == user.Id
                  from permission in role.Permissions
                  select permission;

 // if you don't want repeating permissions use Distinct:
List<Permission> permissionList = permissions.Distinct().ToList();
```

Note that you need to implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in `Permission` to use `Distinct` meaningfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx)

```
var result = (from ru in RoleUserStore
              join role in RoleStore on ru.RoleId equals role.Id
              where ru.UserId == user.Id
              select role.Permissions)
              .SelectMany(user => user).ToList();
```

This is what SelectMany does and I quote MSDN.

`Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable(Of T) and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence.`